# How code_change() function work in gen_server module?

Tags: erlang, distributed, gen-server, gen-event

I am a newbie of `erlang`, So that i have a problem about `gen_server`. I am still unclear how is `code_change()` function work?

Can you explain for me?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Probably duplicate of [Achieving code swapping in Erlang's gen_server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840717/achieving-code-swapping-in-erlangs-gen-server) .

Comment: Thank you a lots, i have resoled :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy really. When `gen_server` is running it contains a state that is passed between calls (the last argument to `handle_call`, `handle_cast` and `handle_info`). If this was a tuple with two elements `{a, b}` and you do a hot code upgrade with [release handler](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_handling.html) and say the new code expects tuple with three elements `{a, b, c}` then you need to convert the state before the new code could use the old state.

You do that with `code_change`. In the [Release Handling Instructions](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_handling.html#id78465) you specify the `update` instruction and then, when Release Handler upgrades the code on the live node, it calls the `code_change` function to convert the state. While the state is being converted the processes is paused, then it resumes with the new state.

You probably don't need to worry about that if you are not using Release Handler to do release upgrades on live nodes. And even then it's used only if the state format has to be changed, which isn't that often.

Comment: Thanks for great help, Amiramix :)

Comment: You are most welcome! Don't forget that you can accept an answer if it answers your question :)