# How to gracefully restart the Elixir App?

Tags: elixir

I have a supervised elixir app which I am running like :- `MIX_ENV=dev mix run`. Now if I change the code, then how can I restart the app gracefully by not killing it first. (Just like we gracefully restart the supervisord process using HUP)

Answer (score 0):

the nitty gritty details of the actual code hot swapping you can find in the answer to this question:

[Achieving code swapping in Erlang's gen_server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840717/achieving-code-swapping-in-erlangs-gen-server)

as to how to automate the process of reloading you can have a look at phoenix and how it does the reloading. the summary of it is it uses fs lib to monitor file system changes and invoke a process similar to the one outlined in the answer to the question above.

Comment: This is a good read but since I am not using gen_server, hence this does not solve my problem